# On fat tails and wrapped distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

As I understand, the concept of *fat tailed* distributions is quite well-defined for usual probability distributions. But what about wrapped distributions?

For instance, consider the wrapped normal distribution and von Mises distribution. They have the following PDFs:
$$f_{\text{wG}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{(\theta-\mu+2\pi k)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right),$$
$$f_{\text{vM}}=\frac{1}{2\pi I_0(\kappa)}\exp\left\{+\kappa\cos(\theta-\mu)\right\}.$$
Let me compare the variance (circular) for these distributions,
$$v_{\text{wG}}^2=1-e^{-\sigma^2/2},\quad v_{vM}^2=1-\frac{I_1(\kappa)}{I_0(\kappa)}$$
Let $\sigma^{-1}=\kappa$ (for me it seems reasonable) and plot variances (see fig.)

[image]

This plot and expressions for variances allude me to think that von Mises distributions is (in some sense) "more heavily tailed" than the wrapped Gaussian.

To be honest, I am very unnurtured in mathematical statistics, so I do not know a rigirous way to show presence of fat tail for a given distribution. As I remember, the kurtosis is one of quite good measures to check for fat tail.

However, based on my recent discoveries with standard deviation and variance for wrapped distributions, I have a vague feeling that the kurtosis can be look very different from the usual definition for usual distributions.

So, I have two questions:

1. **Does it make sense to speak about fat tails for wrapped distributions?**
2. **Which measures and tools one can use in order to investigate an existence of fat tails for usual distribution and for wrapped distributions?**

Comment: A uniform distribution on an interval such as $[0,2\pi)$ is not usual regarded as "fat-tailed".  But you cannot get anything more "fat-tailed" on a circular distribution than a uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Henry , I understand the point, I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quite comrehensive discussion of this topics can be found in book "Directional statistics" by K. Mardia & P. E. Jupp.

The motivation to define circular standard deviation in such way lies in the fact that circular normal distribution have dispersion
$$1-\nu = e^{-\sigma^2/2}.$$
The kurtosis is defined as
$$k=\frac{\bar{\alpha}_2-\rho^4}{(1-\rho)^2},$$
where $\rho$ is the modulus the first momentum and $\bar{\alpha}_2=\mathbb{E}[\cos\,2(\theta-\mu)].$